# How can I get the content of an url and write into new file using HTMLSession in Python?

Tags: python, file, web-scraping, htmlsession

In beautifulsoup, we use response.content to render the text of the URL and create new file. What should we write if we use HTMLSession from requests_html instead of beautifulsoup?

For example,

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from requests_html import HTMLSession

session = HTMLSession()

# Specify the DOI here
URL="https://academic.oup.com/qje/article/126/4/1593/17089543/qjr041.pdf" 
r = session.get(URL,allow_redirects=True)
with open(pdf_title, "wb") as new_pdf:
    print(f"Begin writing to {pdf_title}")
    new_pdf.write(r.html.content) # This line is not working
```

Comment: You are not fetching HTML.  You are downloading a binary file.  You would not use `beautifulsoup` for this, nor should you use `requests_html`.  `requests` by itself will do it.

Comment: Okay. Then could you tell me how should I update?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all you need, although when I do this, I get "request forbidden by administrative rules".  Presumably, you have the key to get past this.

```
import requests

pdf_title = "xyz.pdf"
URL="https://academic.oup.com/qje/article/126/4/1593/17089543/qjr041.pdf" 
r = requests.get(URL,allow_redirects=True)
with open(pdf_title, "wb") as new_pdf:
    new_pdf.write(r.content)
```